# React Display component after click on card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I creating simple app. It must be app with information about pokemons. So I need to create, when user click on pokeCard, Sidebar info.
How it look now:
[image]

So, Sidebar is must to be, it can be, for example, only white background.
I think about styled-components, but I not sure, that this would be the right decision

How to do it with functional Component?

**Wrapper**

```
  const [SelectedPokemonIndex, setSelectedPokemonIndex] = useState();
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={24} sm={14} lg={16}>
        <Pokemons
          PokemonsList={PokemonsList}
          loadMoreItems={loadMoreItems}
          Loading={Loading}
          onClickPoke={(pokemonId) => {
            fetchPokemonDetails(pokemonId);
            fetchPokemon(pokemonId);
            fetchPokemonStats(pokemonId);
            setSelectedPokemonIndex(pokemonId);
          }}
        />
      </Col>
      <Col xs={24} sm={10} lg={8}>
        <About
          pokemon={SelectedPokemon}
          PokemonTypes={PokemonTypes}
          PokemonStats={PokemonStats}
          index={SelectedPokemonIndex}
          LoadingForSelectedPokemon={LoadingForSelectedPokemon}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

export default Wrapper;
```

**Child component of wrapper**

```
function Pokemons(props) {
  let { PokemonsList, loadMoreItems, Loading, onClickPoke } = props;


  return (

                <GridCard
                  image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${++index}.png`}
                  pokemonId={index}
                  pokemonName={pokemon.name}
                  pokemonUrl={pokemon.url}
                  onClickPoke={onClickPoke}
                />
```

**PokeCard**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Col, Typography } from "antd";
import "./GridCards.css";

const { Title } = Typography;

function GridCards(props) {
  let { key, image, pokemonName, pokemonUrl, pokemonId } = props;


  return (
    <Col
      key={key}
      lg={8}
      md={12}
      xs={24}
      onClick={() => {
        props.onClickPoke(pokemonId);
      }}
    >
      <div
        className="poke-card"
        }}
      >
        <img alt={pokemonName} src={image} />
        {LoadingForPokemon && <div>Loading...</div>}
      </div>
    </Col>
  );
}

export default GridCards;
```

**This is Sidebar, what must to be change:**

```
function About(props) {
  let {
    pokemon,
    LoadingForSelectedPokemon,
    index,
    PokemonTypes,
    PokemonStats,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <PokemonDetails
        pokemonName={pokemon.name}
        pokemonId={pokemon.id}
        pokemon={pokemon}
        LoadingForSelectedPokemon={LoadingForSelectedPokemon}
        image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${index}.png`}
        PokemonTypes={PokemonTypes}
        PokemonStats={PokemonStats}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've currently got?

Comment: @ellitt few secs

Comment: @ellitt I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my question.

Its only need to set isAboutShown

```
 const [isAboutShown, setAboutShow] = useState(false);
```

And onClick I coding `setAboutShow(true)`
How to display component?

```
{isAboutShown && (
          <About/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question and there's a lot going on in your code, but I think you need to move some state management around.

In your GridCards component, give it a prop called `onCardClick` and call that function in the onClick of the `<Col>` component you're using. It'll look something like this:

```
function GridCard(props) {
  const { key, image, pokemonName, pokemonUrl, pokemonId, onCardClick } = props;

  return (
    <Col
      key={key}
      lg={8}
      md={12}
      xs={24}
      onClick={() => onCardClick()}
    >
      <div
        className="poke-card"
      >
        <img alt={pokemonName} src={image} />
        {LoadingForPokemon && <div>Loading...</div>}
      </div>
    </Col>
  );
}

export default GridCard;
```

Then in your wrapper components, instead of using the Pokemons component, I think you can just use your GridCard component and map on whatever data you're using to render out the cards currently.

So something like this:

```
export default function Wrapper() {
  const [selectedPokemon, setSelectedPokemon] = useState(null);

  // data is whatever you have to iterate over to put data into your cards
  const pokemonCards = data.map((p, idx) => {
    return (
      <GridCard
        key={idx}
        image={p.image}
        pokemonName={p.pokemonName}
        onCardClick={() => setSelectedPokemon(p)}
      ></GridCard>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={24} sm={14} lg={16}>
        {pokemonCards}
      </Col>
      <Col xs={24} sm={10} lg={8}>
        <About pokemon={selectedPokemon} />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

Basically, what you should try and accomplish is letting each GridCard component contain all the necessary information for your About component, so that when you click on a GridCard your Wrapper's state can update with a `selectedPokemon` and then pass that back down into your About component.